# $node->nextSibling always giving DOMAttr (text node only)

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am getting following error while Traversing DOM in PHP

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute()

What I am doing is, I am traversing DOM Nodes one-by-one. But in some cases I am not getting Proper DOM node like from which I can get specific Attribute. As I am getting DOMText Node, ->nodeType==3 always (not DOM Node, ->nodeType == 1), hence I am not able to fetch any Attribute of returned DOM Node.

I am fetching Next DOM Node using below syntax in PHP

```
$node = $node->nextSibling;
```

and in some cases I also require to fetch Previous Nodes as well like this

```
$node = $node->previousSibling;
```

Now, my question is, How can I get proper DOM Node?

I have tried below function

```
function GetNode($oNode)
{
    while($oNode->nodeType != 1)
        $oNode = $oNode->previousSibling;
    return $oNode;
}
```

with checking condition (where I have used that Node) like

```
while($node && !empty($node) && $node->nodeType == 1 && !preg_match("/^Abc/",$node->getAttribute('class')))
{
    //further code
    $node = $node->nextSibling;
    $node = GetNode($node);
}
```

But now problem occurs that it goes in infinite loop because it's returning always nodeType == 1 and does not terminating loop.

Comment: Your `GetNode` doesn't change the value of `$oNode`, that's why it loops forever.

Comment: Please post example of xml/html file you are prsing. It seems to me that some nodes contain both children element nodes and text nodes

Comment: @DCoder, I have updated code. It was printing mistake here but not in actual code :)

Comment: @NullVoid DOMText nodes have parent nodes.. why not make use of the `->parentNode` attribute?

Comment: @Prasanth, Sometimes I got DOMText node in `!preg_match("/^Abc/",$node->getAttribute('class'))` and not always. That's why I can't go always for `->parentNode`.

Comment: Just look into [DOMXPath](http://php.net/DOMXPath). it'll solve all your problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text node is a dom element as any other. It appears because there are plain text between tags in your xml (e.g. newline char). So you should just check nodeType and skip text nodes.

In your code you have a mistake in "GetNode" function: you should use $oNode->nextSibling instead of $oNode->previousSibling.

P.S. modern browsers have .nextElementSibling property that skips text nodes ;)